# Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters - PnP Powershell - Add-PnPCustomAction

Tags: powershell, foreach

i keep the error i put in the title when trying to iterate through a csv file of sharepoint sites and add this custom action.

```
#Connect PnPOnline
Connect-pnponline -Url "https://0rl3f-admin.sharepoint.com/" -Interactive

#Config Variables
$CSVFilePath = "C:\temp\BannerForEachTestCSV.csv"
 
#Get data from CSV File
$Sites = Import-Csv -Path $CSVFilePath
 
#Run script to apply the banner to each site
ForEach ($Site in $Sites) {


Add-PnPCustomAction `
  -Title "CustomMessageBanner" `
  -Name "CustomMessageBanner" `
  -Location "ClientSideExtension.ApplicationCustomizer" `
  -ClientSideComponentId "1e2688c4-99d8-4897-8871-a9c151ccfc87" `
  -ClientSideComponentProperties "{`"message`":`"Sample site-scoped message banner text.`"}",
                                   `"textColor`":`"#333`",
                                   `"backgroundColor`":`"#ffffc6`",
                                   `"textFontSizePx`":11,
                                   `"bannerHeightPx`":27,
                                   `"disableSiteAdminUI`":`"true`" }" `
  -Scope Site `
  -Url $Site
  
}
```

If I take the parameter -Url out, it runs without error, but doesn't do anything.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

I have tried using variations of the -Url parameter, but receive the same message.

Comment: Looking [at the documentation](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Add-PnPCustomAction.html), it appears that `-Url` and the `-ClientSideComponent*` parameters are mutually exclusive